# ToolBar navigation button

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, toolbar, android-button

This is my Toolbar:
[image: my toolbar]

And this is Gmail app Toolbar:
[image: gmail toolbar]

I want to have the button which open the navigation drawer that the Gmail app has.

How can I achive that?

This is my ToolBar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
    android:background="#EDAA00" />
```

This is my theme of the app:

```
<style name="noActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
```

This is my code that create the toolbar:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

...

```
 mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                getActivity(),                    /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,                    /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.drawable.ic_drawer,             /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
        )
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show us your code too

Comment: Try removing `app:theme=` from the toolbar. If you still have troubles check this repo on how to implement that toolbar https://github.com/kanytu/android-material-drawer-template

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I discovered that the problem is that I have wrong `@drawable/ic_drawer`, and because of that I have the wrong image. How can I have the correct image so it will be like the Gmail app?

Comment: hii need ur help bro..i had implemented same thing but cant get proper output ..my ic_drawer is not visible

Comment: @Tufan What do you mean by not visible?

Comment: i can display my ic_drawer button in my layout

Comment: this is my action_bar_activity   http://paste.ofcode.org/NBLbKsdvLJXXQjKvqCzKaz    this is my main activity    http://paste.ofcode.org/de8TEj4C5huDSTNiULVQix   and this is my subactivity which extends action_bar_activity   http://paste.ofcode.org/3aQHHGk73VQy5zaHugEbtQm

Comment: m trying from morning help me bro..i want to display ic_drawer with action bar or toolbar but i cant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added to the drawable new `ic_drawer` of this photo:
[image: ic_drawable]

Answer (score 1):

us a code like this in the onCreate:

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_awesome_toolbar);// Supported toolbar
drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout); //this is the navigation drawer
content_frame=(FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_close){
            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                float moveFactor = (getActivity().findViewById(R.id.left_drawer).getWidth() * slideOffset);

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
                {
                    content_frame.setTranslationX(moveFactor);
                }
                else
                {
                    TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(lastTranslate, moveFactor, 0.0f, 0.0f);
                    anim.setDuration(0);
                    anim.setFillAfter(true);
                    content_frame.startAnimation(anim);
                    lastTranslate = moveFactor;
                }
                super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
            }
        };
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        drawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });

 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(drawerListview);
        } else super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

but don't forget to the v7 support library:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
```

without adding any drawable to the toolbar ActionBarDrawerToggle v7 add it and give it animation, and when the drawer is open it transforme to a back button

See this link too [Drawer Arrow Drawable](http://chrisrenke.com/drawerarrowdrawable/)

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I discovered that the problem is that I have wrong @drawable/ic_drawer, and because of that I have the wrong image. How can I have the correct image so it will be like the Gmail app?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following style:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_drawer</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>
```

Please refer this [link](https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/).

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I discovered that the problem is that I have wrong `@drawable/ic_drawer`, and because of that I have the wrong image. How can I have the correct image so it will be like the Gmail app?

Comment: You can see this link : 
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html#ActionBarIcon

Comment: I am using that code, the problem is that I have different `@drawable/ic_drawer`

Comment: Try after removing this,

<item name="android:homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/ic_drawer</item>

Comment: Still the same... I just need the image if the correct ic_drawer and everything will be right- where can I get it?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a deprecated constructor for ActionBarDrawerToggle.

```
 mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            getActivity(),                    /* host Activity */
            mDrawerLayout,                    /* DrawerLayout object */
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,             /* nav drawer image to replace 'Up' caret */
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
            R.string.navigation_drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
    )
```

If you want to have the same exact behavior as Gmail just remove the R.drawable.ic_drawer.

```
 mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                getActivity(),                    /* host Activity */
                mDrawerLayout,                    /* DrawerLayout object */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
        )
```

You might need to upgrade you appcompat version to 21 at least.